# Pygame game code - character stopped moving

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating a simple Pygame game and the character was moving around the screen when I pressed the arrow keys. I have added an intro which has the title and 2 buttons and when the green button is pressed to start the game, the game loads but the character no longer moves when the keys are pressed. Can someone please help tell me why the arrow keys no longer move the character? Thank you!

Code:

```
import time
#we need to initiate pygame at the start of all our code
pygame.init()
display_width = 800
display_height = 600

#creating window, in tuple is width and height of screen
win = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))

x = (display_width * 0.45)
y = (display_height * 0.8)

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (200,0,0)
green = (0,200,0)
bright_red = (255, 0, 0)
bright_green = (0,255,0)



def crash():
    message_display('Item collected')

#button
def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac, action=None):
  mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
  click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    #print(mouse)
  if x + w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
    pygame.draw.rect(win, ac, (x,y,w,h))
    if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
      action()


def collect_item():
  message_display('Do you want to pick up item?')

  button("YES",150,450,100,50,green, bright_green, game_loop)
  button("NO",550,450,100, 50, red, bright_red, game_loop)



#def game_loop():
  #x = (display_width * 0.45)
  #y = (display_height * 0.8)
  #x_change = 0
  #dodged = 0
  #run = True

#good idea to create a screen width variable
screenWidth = 800

#Name of our window
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

#Code for importing multiple images of the animated sprite

#walk right animation
walkRight = [pygame.image.load('R1.PNG'), pygame.image.load('R2.PNG'), pygame.image.load('R3.PNG')]

#walk left animation
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('L1.PNG'), pygame.image.load('L2.PNG'), pygame.image.load('L3.PNG')]

#back ground image load in
bg = pygame.image.load('grass11.jpg')

#Basic standing sprite, it is the still image. shows this character when they are not moving
char = pygame.image.load('front.PNG')


def puff(x,y):
  win.blit(char (x,y))




#allows us to change our fps in the game
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

swordIMG = pygame.image.load('smallsword.png')

staffIMG = pygame.image.load('staff.png')

chestIMG = pygame.image.load('chest.png')

coinIMG = pygame.image.load('coin.png')

def text_objects(text, font):
  textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
  return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
  largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 115)
  TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
  TextRect.center = ((display_width/2)), ((display_height/2))
  win.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

  pygame.display.update() 

  time.sleep(2)

def quitgame():
  pygame.quit()
  quit()

def game_intro():
  intro = True
  while intro:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        quit()
    win.fill(white)
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("TITLE", largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2)), ((display_height/2))
    win.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    #Button
    button("GO!",150,450,100,50,green, bright_green, game_loop)
    button("Quit",550,450,100, 50, red, bright_red, quitgame)
    pygame.display.update()

#creating character
#x = 50
#y = 400
#width and height of sprite
width = 100 
height = 100

#staff
staffwidth = 94
staffheight = 106

#coin
coinwidth = 74
coinheight = 74

#chest
chestwidth = 84
chestheight = 84

#velocity is how fast the character moves
vel = 5

left = False
right = False
walkCount = 0 

#function which redraws the game window, this area is for drawing, we do not draw in main loop
def redrawGameWindow():
    #x = (display_width * 0.45)
    #y = (display_height * 0.8)
    global walkCount
    win.blit(bg, (0,0)) #back ground image
    win.blit(swordIMG,(600,400))
    win.blit(staffIMG, (70, 60))
    win.blit(chestIMG, (600, 100))
    win.blit(coinIMG, (350,300))

    if walkCount + 1 >= 0:
        walkCount = 0

    if left:
        win.blit(walkLeft[walkCount], (x,y)) #displaying walk left sprite
        walkCount += 1

    elif right:
        win.blit(walkRight[walkCount], (x,y))
        walkCount += 1
    #repeat for up and down
    else:
        win.blit(char, (x,y)) #if we are not moving we blit our character


    pygame.display.update() #if we want something to show on the screen in pygame, we must update the screen



#main loop for program
#main loop
#run the variable

#def game_loop():
  #redrawGameWindow()
  #x = (display_width * 0.45)
  #y = (display_height * 0.8)
  #x_change = 0
  #dodged = 0

def game_loop(): 
  x = (display_width * 0.45)
  y = (display_height * 0.8)

  x_change = 0

  dodged = 0

  run = True

  while run:

      #redrawGameWindow()
      #game_intro()
      clock.tick(27) #sets fps to 20 seconds
      #pygame.time.delay(100) #clock in pgyame, parameter is milliseconds

      for event in pygame.event.get(): #event is what player does eg. mouse click or key press
          if event.type == pygame.QUIT: #if they click the x button (quit)
              run = FALSE #loop = false

      #using arrow keys to move shape
      # all of the and's mean the shape cannot move off the screen
      keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

      if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel:
          x -= vel
          left = True
          right = False


      elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 800 - width - vel: #screen width - width of character
          x += vel
          right = True
          left = False

      elif keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > vel:
          y -= vel
          up = True
          down = False

      elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y <  600 - height - vel:
          y += vel
          down = True
          up = False

      else:
          right = False
          left = False
          up = False
          down = False
          walkCount = 0

      if x < 100  - vel and x > 50 - vel and y > 40 - vel and y < 70:
          crash()

      if x > 600 - vel and x < 703 - vel and y > 400 - vel and y < 502 - vel:
          crash()

      if x > 330 - vel and x < 420 - vel and y > 280 - vel and y < 300 - vel:
          crash()

      if x > 600 - vel and x < 684 - vel and y > 100 - vel and y < 184 - vel:
        crash()

      redrawGameWindow()     
      #if y < 160 - vel and y > 90 - vel:
          #crash()

game_intro()
#game_loop() 
#redrawGameWindow() #call function
pygame.quit #game ends
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 This is because I call game_intro() and when you press the 'start' button, it calls game_loop()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables `x`, `y`, `right`, `left`, `up`, `down` and `walkCount` are variables in global name space. You have to use the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt), if you want to write to the variables in global namespace, from within the function `game_loop`:

```py
def game_loop(): 
  global x, y, left, right, up, down, walkCount

  x = (display_width * 0.45)
  y = (display_height * 0.8)

  x_change = 0
  dodged = 0
  run = True
  while run:  

    # [...]
```

---

Furthermore, the buttons are not drawn, if the mouse is not on the buttons:

```py
def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac, action=None):
  mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
  click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

  pygame.draw.rect(win, ic, (x,y,w,h)) # <--- This line is missing

  if x + w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
    pygame.draw.rect(win, ac, (x,y,w,h))
    if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
      action()
```

Comment: I have created a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62227424/creating-simple-python-game-button-functions I was wondering if you would please be able to have a look at it as I was talking to someone about it but they have left and I am struggling to correct my code. I am running out of time as my assignment is due in 1 hour so any help would be appreciated 