# Creating simple python game - button functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am creating a simple python game and in it, a character moves around to collect items. I have created the character moving around and when they go over an item (an image), text pops up asking if they want to pick up the item as well as buttons which say 'yes' and 'no'.

If they click yes, the item should disappear and then they return to the game. If they click no, the item will stay there and they should return to the game. To get rid of the item, I have tried to redraw the screen without the item they collect. However, I do not know how to return to the game after they click yes or no. If the button function returns them to `game_loop()` then the `redrawGameWindow()` function will activate, moving the character back to its starting position and returning the item. Does anyone know how to fix this/ what function to put in my buttons? Thank you!

Code:

````
import time
import sys
#we need to initiate pygame at the start of all our code
pygame.init()
display_width = 800
display_height = 600

#creating window, in tuple is width and height of screen
win = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))

x = (display_width * 0.45)
y = (display_height * 0.8)

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (200,0,0)
green = (0,200,0)
bright_red = (255, 0, 0)
bright_green = (0,255,0)
purple = (183,52,235)
pink = (255, 209, 237)
blue = (184, 243, 255)
bright_blue = (120, 232, 255)
bright_pink = (247, 148, 208)
transparent = (0, 0, 0, 0)




def crash():
    message_display('Item collected')

#button
def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac, action=None):
  mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
  click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

  pygame.draw.rect(win, ic, (x,y,w,h))
    #print(mouse)
  if x + w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
    pygame.draw.rect(win, ac, (x,y,w,h))
    if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
      action()

  else:
    pygame.draw.rect(win, ic, (x,y,w,h))
  smallText = pygame.font.Font("Gameplay.ttf", 20)
  textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
  textRect.center = ((x+(w/2), y+(h/2)))
  win.blit(textSurf, textRect)


def collect_item():


  button("YES",150,450,100,50,green, bright_green, remove_image)
  button("NO",550,450,100, 50, red, bright_red, game_loop)
  message_display('Do you want to pick up item?')

  #pygame.display.update()



#def game_loop():
  #x = (display_width * 0.45)
  #y = (display_height * 0.8)
  #x_change = 0
  #dodged = 0
  #run = True

#good idea to create a screen width variable
screenWidth = 800

#Name of our window
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

#Code for importing multiple images of the animated sprite

#walk right animation
walkRight = [pygame.image.load('R1.PNG'), pygame.image.load('R2.PNG'), pygame.image.load('R3.PNG')]

#walk left animation
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('L1.PNG'), pygame.image.load('L2.PNG'), pygame.image.load('L3.PNG')]

#back ground image load in
bg = pygame.image.load('flowergrass.PNG')

#Basic standing sprite, it is the still image. shows this character when they are not moving
char = pygame.image.load('front.PNG')


def puff(x,y):
  win.blit(char (x,y))




#allows us to change our fps in the game
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

swordIMG = pygame.image.load('smallsword.png')

staffIMG = pygame.image.load('staff.png')

chestIMG = pygame.image.load('chest.png')

coinIMG = pygame.image.load('coin.png')

def text_objects(text, font):
  textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
  return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
  largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 115)
  TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
  TextRect.center = ((display_width/2)), ((display_height/2))
  win.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

  pygame.display.update() 

  time.sleep(2)

def quitgame():
  pygame.quit()
  quit()

def game_intro():
  intro = True
  while intro:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        quit()
    win.fill(white)
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('StitchWarrior demo.ttf', 115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Title", largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2)), ((display_height/2))
    win.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    #Button
    button("GO!",150,450,100,50, blue, bright_blue, game_loop)
    button("Quit",550,450,100, 50, pink, bright_pink, quitgame)
    pygame.display.update()

#creating character
x = 60
y = 450
#width and height of sprite
width = 100 
height = 100

#staff
staffwidth = 94
staffheight = 106

#coin
coinwidth = 74
coinheight = 74

#chest
chestwidth = 84
chestheight = 84

def remove_image():
  win.blit(bg, (0,0))
  char
  swordIMG
  chestIMG
  coinIMG
  sys.exit()

#velocity is how fast the character moves
vel = 5

left = False
right = False
walkCount = 0 

#function which redraws the game window, this area is for drawing, we do not draw in main loop
def redrawGameWindow():
    #x = (display_width * 0.45)
    #y = (display_height * 0.8)
    global walkCount
    win.blit(bg, (0,0)) #back ground image
    win.blit(swordIMG,(600,400))
    win.blit(staffIMG, (70, 60))
    win.blit(chestIMG, (600, 100))
    win.blit(coinIMG, (350,300))

    if walkCount + 1 >= 0:
        walkCount = 0

    if left:
        win.blit(walkLeft[walkCount], (x,y)) #displaying walk left sprite
        walkCount += 1

    elif right:
        win.blit(walkRight[walkCount], (x,y))
        walkCount += 1
    #repeat for up and down
    else:
        win.blit(char, (x,y)) #if we are not moving we blit our character


    pygame.display.update() #if we want something to show on the screen in pygame, we must update the screen



#main loop for program
#main loop
#run the variable

#def game_loop():
  #redrawGameWindow()
  #x = (display_width * 0.45)
  #y = (display_height * 0.8)
  #x_change = 0
  #dodged = 0

def game_loop(): 
  global x, y, left, right, up, down, walkCount

  #x = (display_width * 0.45)
  #y = (display_height * 0.8)

  x_change = 0

  dodged = 0

  run = True

  while run:

      #redrawGameWindow()
      #game_intro()
      clock.tick(27) #sets fps to 20 seconds
      #pygame.time.delay(100) #clock in pgyame, parameter is milliseconds

      for event in pygame.event.get(): #event is what player does eg. mouse click or key press
          if event.type == pygame.QUIT: #if they click the x button (quit)
              run = FALSE #loop = false

      #using arrow keys to move shape
      # all of the and's mean the shape cannot move off the screen
      keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

      if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel:
          x -= vel
          left = True
          right = False


      elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 800 - width - vel: #screen width - width of character
          x += vel
          right = True
          left = False

      elif keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > vel:
          y -= vel
          up = True
          down = False

      elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y <  600 - height - vel:
          y += vel
          down = True
          up = False

      else:
          right = False
          left = False
          up = False
          down = False
          walkCount = 0

      if x < 100  - vel and x > 50 - vel and y > 40 - vel and y < 70:
          collect_item()

      if x > 600 - vel and x < 703 - vel and y > 400 - vel and y < 502 - vel:
          crash()

      if x > 330 - vel and x < 420 - vel and y > 280 - vel and y < 300 - vel:
          crash()

      if x > 600 - vel and x < 684 - vel and y > 100 - vel and y < 184 - vel:
        crash()

      redrawGameWindow()     
      #if y < 160 - vel and y > 90 - vel:
          #crash()

game_intro()
#game_loop() 
#redrawGameWindow() #call function
pygame.quit #game ends```}










**Updated Code**

    {```import pygame
    import time
    import sys
    #we need to initiate pygame at the start of all our code
    pygame.init()
    display_width = 800
    display_height = 600

    #creating window, in tuple is width and height of screen
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))

    x = (display_width * 0.45)
    y = (display_height * 0.8)

    black = (0,0,0)
    white = (255,255,255)
    red = (200,0,0)
    green = (0,200,0)
    bright_red = (255, 0, 0)
    bright_green = (0,255,0)
    purple = (183,52,235)
    pink = (255, 209, 237)
    blue = (184, 243, 255)
    bright_blue = (120, 232, 255)
    bright_pink = (247, 148, 208)
    transparent = (0, 0, 0, 0)




    def remove_image(obj):
        del objs[objs.index(obj)]

    def things_collected(count):
      font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
      text = font.render("Items: " + str(count), True, black)
      win.blit(text, (0,0))

    def crash():
        message_display('Item collected')

    #button
    def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac, action=None, arg=None):
      mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
      click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

      pygame.draw.rect(win, ic, (x,y,w,h))
        #print(mouse)
      if x + w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, ac, (x,y,w,h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
          if arg:
            action(arg)
          else:
            action()

      else:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, ic, (x,y,w,h))
      smallText = pygame.font.Font("Gameplay.ttf", 20)
      textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
      textRect.center = ((x+(w/2), y+(h/2)))
      win.blit(textSurf, textRect)


    def collect_item():


      button("YES",150,450,100,50,blue, bright_blue, remove_image,obj)
      button("NO",550,450,100, 50, pink, bright_pink)
      message_display('Pick up item?')

      #pygame.display.update()



    #def game_loop():
      #x = (display_width * 0.45)
      #y = (display_height * 0.8)
      #x_change = 0
      #dodged = 0
      #run = True

    #good idea to create a screen width variable
    screenWidth = 800

    #Name of our window
    pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

    #Code for importing multiple images of the animated sprite

    #walk right animation
    walkRight = [pygame.image.load('R1.PNG'), pygame.image.load('R2.PNG'), pygame.image.load('R3.PNG')]

    #walk left animation
    walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('L1.PNG'), pygame.image.load('L2.PNG'), pygame.image.load('L3.PNG')]

    #back ground image load in
    bg = pygame.image.load('path.PNG')

    opening_bg = pygame.image.load('openingbg.PNG')

    #Basic standing sprite, it is the still image. shows this character when they are not moving
    char = pygame.image.load('front.PNG')


    def puff(x,y):
      win.blit(char (x,y))




    #allows us to change our fps in the game
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    swordIMG = pygame.image.load('smallsword.png')

    staffIMG = pygame.image.load('staff.png')

    chestIMG = pygame.image.load('chest.png')

    coinIMG = pygame.image.load('coin.png')

    class Object:
        def __init__(self, x, y, image):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.image = image
            self.rect = image.get_rect()
            self.rect.topleft = (self.x, self.y)

    objs = []
    objs.append(Object(600, 400, swordIMG))
    objs.append(Object(70, 60, staffIMG))
    objs.append(Object(600, 100, chestIMG))
    objs.append(Object(350, 300, coinIMG))

    def text_objects(text, font):
      textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
      return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

    def message_display(text):
      largeText = pygame.font.Font('Gameplay.ttf', 50)
      TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
      TextRect.center = ((display_width/2)), ((display_height/2))
      win.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

      pygame.display.update() 

      time.sleep(2)

    def quitgame():
      pygame.quit()
      quit()

    def game_intro():
      intro = True
      while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
          if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        win.blit(opening_bg, (0,0))
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('StitchWarrior demo.ttf', 70)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("The Adventures of Peyia", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2)), ((display_height/4))
        win.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        #Button
        button("GO!",150,450,100,50, blue, bright_blue, game_loop)
        button("Quit",550,450,100, 50, pink, bright_pink, quitgame)
        pygame.display.update()

    #creating character
    x = 60
    y = 450
    #width and height of sprite
    width = 100 
    height = 100

    #staff
    staffwidth = 94
    staffheight = 106

    #coin
    coinwidth = 74
    coinheight = 74

    #chest
    chestwidth = 84
    chestheight = 84

    #def remove_image():
      #win.blit(bg, (0,0))
      #char
      #swordIMG
      #chestIMG
      #coinIMG
      #collected += 1

    #velocity is how fast the character moves
    vel = 5

    left = False
    right = False
    walkCount = 0 

    #function which redraws the game window, this area is for drawing, we do not draw in main loop
    def redrawGameWindow():



        #x = (display_width * 0.45)
        #y = (display_height * 0.8)
        global walkCount
        win.blit(bg, (0,0)) #back ground image
        #win.blit(swordIMG,(600,400))
        #win.blit(staffIMG, (70, 60))
        #win.blit(chestIMG, (600, 100))
        #win.blit(coinIMG, (350,300))
        for obj in objs:
          win.blit(obj.image, obj.rect)

        if walkCount + 1 >= 0:
            walkCount = 0

        if left:
            win.blit(walkLeft[walkCount], (x,y)) #displaying walk left sprite
            walkCount += 1

        elif right:
            win.blit(walkRight[walkCount], (x,y))
            walkCount += 1
        #repeat for up and down
        else:
            win.blit(char, (x,y)) #if we are not moving we blit our character


        pygame.display.update() #if we want something to show on the screen in pygame, we must update the screen



    #main loop for program
    #main loop
    #run the variable

    #def game_loop():
      #redrawGameWindow()
      #x = (display_width * 0.45)
      #y = (display_height * 0.8)
      #x_change = 0
      #dodged = 0

    def game_loop(): 
      global x, y, left, right, up, down, walkCount
      x = 60
      y = 450
      #x = (display_width * 0.45)
      #y = (display_height * 0.8)

      x_change = 0

      collected = 0

      run = True

      while run:
         for obj in reversed(objs): #if delete obj in list while looping through it, the loop will still try to get the deleted obj, so reverse to fix this
          if obj.rect.collidepoint((x + vel, y + vel)):
            collect_item(obj) #give the object so we know which one to delete


          redrawGameWindow()
          #game_intro()
          clock.tick(27) #sets fps to 20 seconds
          #pygame.time.delay(100) #clock in pgyame, parameter is milliseconds
          things_collected(collected)

          for event in pygame.event.get(): #event is what player does eg. mouse click or key press
              if event.type == pygame.QUIT: #if they click the x button (quit)
                  run = FALSE #loop = false

          #using arrow keys to move shape
          # all of the and's mean the shape cannot move off the screen
          keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

          if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel:
              x -= vel
              left = True
              right = False


          elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 800 - width - vel: #screen width - width of character
              x += vel
              right = True
              left = False

          elif keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > vel:
              y -= vel
              up = True
              down = False

          elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y <  600 - height - vel:
              y += vel
              down = True
              up = False

          else:
              right = False
              left = False
              up = False
              down = False
              walkCount = 0

          if x < 100  - vel and x > 50 - vel and y > 40 - vel and y < 70:
              collect_item()

          if x > 600 - vel and x < 703 - vel and y > 400 - vel and y < 502 - vel:
              crash()

          if x > 330 - vel and x < 420 - vel and y > 280 - vel and y < 300 - vel:
              crash()

          if x > 600 - vel and x < 684 - vel and y > 100 - vel and y < 184 - vel:
            crash()

          #redrawGameWindow()     
          #if y < 160 - vel and y > 90 - vel:
              #crash()

    game_intro()
    #game_loop() 
    #redrawGameWindow() #call function
    pygame.quit #game ends
````

Comment: you just need to put obj in the brackets of `collect_items()` in both `def collect_lines(obj)` and `if x < 100  - vel and x > 50 - vel and y > 40 - vel and y < 70:
                  collect_item(obj)`

Comment: @TheBigKahuna Ok I believe the image is now disappearing, however it is still staying on the 'Pick up item?' screen and not returning to the game.

Comment: just to confrim, do you still have the `if x < 100  - vel and x > 50 - vel and y > 40 - vel and y < 70:` at the bottom, becuase it might be because you are calling `collect_item()` twice

Comment: @TheBigKahuna I have collect_item(obj) 2 times in the game loop: `if obj.rect.collidepoint((x + vel, y + vel)):
        collect_item(obj)` and `if x < 100  - vel and x > 50 - vel and y > 40 - vel and y < 166 - vel:
          collect_item(obj)`

Comment: ok, so that will be the problem, my fault for being confusing, the loop with the `collidepoint` is to replace the if statements at the bottom, so when it gets deleted, it will stop checking but the bottom if statements will keep checking

Comment: so delete the bottom if statements, or atleast the one with `collect_items`

Comment: @TheBigKahuna But the if statements in the game loop check to see if the character is overlapping with the items

Comment: So does the `collidepoint`

Comment: @TheBigKahuna so I delete all of this? #if x < 100  - vel and x > 50 - vel and y > 40 - vel and y < 166 - vel:
          #collect_item(obj)
          #remove_image(obj)
            
      #if x > 600 - vel and x < 703 - vel and y > 400 - vel and y < 502 - vel:
          #crash()
            
      #if x > 330 - vel and x < 420 - vel and y > 280 - vel and y < 300 - vel:
          #crash()
            
      #if x > 600 - vel and x < 684 - vel and y > 100 - vel and y < 184 - vel:
        #crash()

Comment: @TheBigKahuna If so, do I need to replace it with something?

Comment: i managed to get your code working, you should use 4 space indents, ive edited it and now works, full code in my answer

Comment: @TheBigKahuna The 'no' button when collecting an item still doesn't seem to work. Is it because the message_display is after the no button so when you press 'no', it just goes back to displaying the message instead of exiting the function? Because if you put the message_display in front of the 'no' button, it doesn't display.

Comment: no, the problem with the no button is you are calling the function every frame, its not that its not returning it does that, 27 times a second to be exact. you need to control when you can call the `collect_item` function, this is a bit more complicated

Comment: @TheBigKahuna When I copy and pasted your code with the squares, the 'no' button still didn't seem to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215448/discussion-between-the-big-kahuna-and-minbutt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way i would do it is have a class for a object, then create the objects and put them in a list, when you draw the window, loop through the list and draw each object, if you want to 'get rid' of a object, delete it from the list, if you want to add an object, add it to the list

here is an example

```py
class Object:
    def __init__(self, x, y, image):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.image = image
        self.rect = image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x, self.y)

objs = []
objs.append(Object(100, 100, swordIMG))
objs.append(Object(300, 400, staffIMG))
objs.append(Object(200, 340, chestIMG))

def redrawGameWindow():
    for obj in objs:
        win.blit(obj.image, obj.rect)

def game_loop():
    while run:
        for obj in reversed(objs): #if delete obj in list while looping through it, the loop will still try to get the deleted obj, so reverse to fix this
            if obj.rect.collidpoint((x + vel, y + vel)):
                collect_item(obj) #give the object so we know which one to delete
```

```
def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac, action=None, arg = None):
  mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
  click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

  pygame.draw.rect(win, ic, (x,y,w,h))
    #print(mouse)
  if x + w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
    pygame.draw.rect(win, ac, (x,y,w,h))
    if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
      if arg:
         action(arg)
      else:
         action()
  else:
    pygame.draw.rect(win, ic, (x,y,w,h))
  smallText = pygame.font.Font("Gameplay.ttf", 20)
  textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
  textRect.center = ((x+(w/2), y+(h/2)))
  win.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def collect_items(obj):
  button("YES",150,450,100,50,green, bright_green, remove_image,obj)
  button("NO",550,450,100, 50, red, bright_red)
  message_display('Do you want to pick up item?')

def remove_image(obj):
    del objs[objs.index(obj)]
```

and the button function looks good, ive recently tried to make a customizable but simple button for pygame [here](https://github.com/TheBigKahuna353/PygameUI) if you want some inspiration

---

````
import time
import sys
import pygame
#we need to initiate pygame at the start of all our code
pygame.init()
display_width = 800
display_height = 600

#creating window, in tuple is width and height of screen
win = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))

x = (display_width * 0.45)
y = (display_height * 0.8)

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (200,0,0)
green = (0,200,0)
bright_red = (255, 0, 0)
bright_green = (0,255,0)
purple = (183,52,235)
pink = (255, 209, 237)
blue = (184, 243, 255)
bright_blue = (120, 232, 255)
bright_pink = (247, 148, 208)
transparent = (0, 0, 0, 0)

#allows us to change our fps in the game
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

swordIMG = pygame.Surface((40,40))
swordIMG.fill((255,0,0))

staffIMG = swordIMG

chestIMG = swordIMG

coinIMG = swordIMG

#good idea to create a screen width variable
screenWidth = 800

#Name of our window
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

#Code for importing multiple images of the animated sprite

img = pygame.Surface((50,50))
img.fill((0,255,0))

#walk right animation
walkRight = [img, img, img]

#walk left animation
walkLeft = walkRight

#back ground image load in
bg = pygame.Surface((800,800))
bg.fill((255,255,255))

#Basic standing sprite, it is the still image. shows this character when they are not moving
char = pygame.Surface((50,50))
char.fill((0,255,0))

#velocity is how fast the character moves
vel = 5

left = False
right = False
walkCount = 0 

#creating character
x = 60
y = 450
#width and height of sprite
width = 100 
height = 100

#staff
staffwidth = 94
staffheight = 106

#coin
coinwidth = 74
coinheight = 74

#chest
chestwidth = 84
chestheight = 84

class Object:
    def __init__(self, x, y, image):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.image = image
        self.rect = image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x, self.y)

objs = []
objs.append(Object(600, 400, swordIMG))
objs.append(Object(70, 60, staffIMG))
objs.append(Object(600, 100, chestIMG))
objs.append(Object(350, 300, coinIMG))

can_pickup = True
prev_frame_over_Object = False


def crash():
    message_display('Item collected')

#button
def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac, action=None, arg=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    pygame.draw.rect(win, ic, (x,y,w,h))
    #print(mouse)
    if x + w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, ac, (x,y,w,h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            if arg:
                action(arg)
            else:
                action()

    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, ic, (x,y,w,h))
        smallText = pygame.font.Font(pygame.font.match_font('calibri'), 20)
        textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
        textRect.center = ((x+(w/2), y+(h/2)))
        win.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def NO():
    global can_pickup
    can_pickup = False


def collect_item(obj):

    button("YES",150,450,100,50,green, bright_green, remove_image, obj)
    message_display('Do you want to pick up item?')
    button("NO",550,450,100, 50, red, bright_red, NO)


def puff(x,y):
    win.blit(char (x,y))

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2)), ((display_height/2))
    win.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

def quitgame():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

def game_intro():
    intro = True
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        win.fill(white)
        largeText = pygame.font.Font(pygame.font.match_font('calibri'), 115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Title", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2)), ((display_height/2))
        win.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        #Button
        button("GO!",150,450,100,50, blue, bright_blue, game_loop)
        button("Quit",550,450,100, 50, pink, bright_pink, quitgame)
        pygame.display.update()


def remove_image(obj):
    del objs[objs.index(obj)]

#function which redraws the game window, this area is for drawing, we do not draw in main loop
def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkCount
    win.blit(bg, (0,0)) #back ground image
    for obj in objs:
        win.blit(obj.image, obj.rect)

    if walkCount + 1 >= 0:
        walkCount = 0

    if left:
        win.blit(walkLeft[walkCount], (x,y)) #displaying walk left sprite
        walkCount += 1

    elif right:
        win.blit(walkRight[walkCount], (x,y))
        walkCount += 1
    #repeat for up and down
    else:
        win.blit(char, (x,y)) #if we are not moving we blit our character



def game_loop(): 
    global x, y, left, right, up, down, walkCount, prev_frame_over_Object, can_pickup

    x_change = 0

    dodged = 0

    run = True

    while run:

        #redrawGameWindow()
        #game_intro()
        clock.tick(27) #sets fps to 20 seconds
        #pygame.time.delay(100) #clock in pgyame, parameter is milliseconds

        for event in pygame.event.get(): #event is what player does eg. mouse click or key press
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: #if they click the x button (quit)
                run = False #loop = false

        #using arrow keys to move shape
        # all of the and's mean the shape cannot move off the screen
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel:
            x -= vel
            left = True
            right = False

        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 800 - width - vel: #screen width - width of character
            x += vel
            right = True
            left = False

        elif keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > vel:
            y -= vel
            up = True
            down = False

        elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y <  600 - height - vel:
            y += vel
            down = True
            up = False

        else:
            right = False
            left = False
            up = False
            down = False
            walkCount = 0

        redrawGameWindow()     

        is_over = False

        for obj in reversed(objs): #if delete obj in list while looping through it, the loop will still try to get the deleted obj, so reverse to fix this
            if obj.rect.collidepoint((x + vel, y + vel)):
                is_over = True
                if prev_frame_over_Object == False:
                    can_pickup = True
                if can_pickup:
                    collect_item(obj) #give the object so we know which one to delete

        prev_frame_over_Object = is_over
        pygame.display.update() #if we want something to show on the screen in pygame, we must update the screen

game_intro()
pygame.quit #game ends```}
````

this code works, i found that you had time.sleep in the text display so the fps dropped to half a frame per second, but once that was out and i moved the order of drawing, everything seemed to work, i dont have the images you have so i changed them to squares, they are at the top, dont copy paste them

Comment: @Minbutt no, the class instance, its like doing `collect_item(objs[1])`

Comment: When you say to give the object, do you mean to put 'chestIMG' in for example? like collect_item(chestIMG) ? Also, should I continue with the collect_item() function?

Comment: @Minbutt the `collect_item()` seems fine, it is just a few lines so you could just put those in instead of calling it but, what your doing now is works fine and looks clean

Comment: with `def redrawGameWindow():
    for obj in objs:
        win.blit(obj.image, obj.rect)` are you saying to put that in my already existing redrawGameWindow() function?

Comment: @Minbutt yes, so instead of blitting all objects manually, you can loop through them so you can replace the `win.blit(swordIMG,(600,400))` and the other IMG's with the loop

Comment: are the numbers in `objs.append(Object(100, 100, swordIMG))
objs.append(Object(300, 400, staffIMG))
objs.append(Object(200, 340, chestIMG))` just the x and y of where they are being blitted on the screen?

Comment: yes, i just put random numbers, but they should be the numbers you put when blitting them. `win.blit(swordIMG,(600,400))` would be `Object(600,400,swordIMG)`

Comment: When I try to run the program I get an error message saying: if obj.rect.collidpoint((x + vel, y + vel)):
AttributeError: 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'collidpoint'

Comment: I have changed the method of loading in the images to your method, but they are all loading in the top left corner of the screen instead of their x and y coordinates.

Comment: @Minbutt my fault again, i forgot to change the x and y of the rect, i updated the answer, you just need to change the rect.x and rect.y to x and y

Comment: in the `def collect_item():
  
  
  button("YES",150,450,100,50,blue, bright_blue, remove_image)
  button("NO",550,450,100, 50, pink, bright_pink, game_loop)
  message_display('Pick up item?')` function, it has the buttons to ask whether to pick up the item or not. In the yes button, the function is remove_image and I should leave that because you have defined a new remove_image function, but what function should I put in the 'no' button to return to the game?

Comment: @Minbutt yes, leave it in, but for the 'no' button, leave it blank so it finishes running the function and returns to the line where you called `collect_item()` in `game_loop`, basically returning to where you left off, which is what you want, but since the player will still be in the object, the no button will continue to show up, so to sum it up, leaving it blank will leave it there and should be fine

Comment: Since I want to remove each image if they are collected do I put all of them in the game loop like this:  `while run:
     for obj in reversed(objs): #if delete obj in list while looping through it, the loop will still try to get the deleted obj, so reverse to fix this
      if obj.rect.collidepoint((x + vel, y + vel)):
        collect_item(objs[1]) #give the object so we know which one to delete
        collect_item(objs[2])
        collect_item(objs[3])
        collect_item(objs[4])`

Comment: its kinda hard to read the code, maybe try editing your answer to show what you have done, but not quite, the point of the loop is so you dont need to go `collect_item(objs[some number])`, it figures out which one for you, so like in my answer, use `obj`, do you need me to explain more?

Comment: Ok I changed it back to just `collect_item(obj)` but when I click the 'yes' button to pick up the object I get an error message saying: TypeError: remove_image() missing 1 required positional argument: 'obj'

Comment: @Minbutt thats an annoying problem, a quick fix is add a arg param, i updated the answer, now call the button in `collect_item` and send obj as arg, its not ideal but it should work

Comment: I have edited my code according to your updated answer but I am getting an error message:     button("YES",150,450,100,50,blue, bright_blue, remove_image,obj)
NameError: name 'obj' is not defined, I have included my updated code in my original question underneath my original code if you want to look at it and see if anything is wrong